Filling space between 3 sketches | Fusion 360

How would I go about filling the space between these 3 sketches. As I am new to Fusion 360, I don't know all the features. I heard about Lofting but that doesn't seem to work.
These sketches constrain the shape of my model. I just want it solid now.
It would be very nice, if you could help.

I believe you could extrude all three of the sketches as far as needed to "clear" the other ones (as individual bodies) and then use a boolean operation on those bodies that only keeps the parts that are common to all three.

How does this apply to 3D printing?
